# PHP Warning: mail(): Found numeric header

Tags: php, email

I am using following script to send email through PHP. However, I am getting error `"PHP Warning:  mail(): Found numeric header (4) in /home/....public_html/.../sendemail.php on line 16"` Any help please.

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'xxxxx@xmail.com';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
die;
```

Comment: [Consult the manual on `mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) then find and compare what you have and what the manual shows how to use the headers as arrays. You'll see how simple a fix this is.

Comment: It says "7.2.0  The additional_headers parameter now also accepts an array. " I am exactly using PHP 7.2 and headers as suggested in the manual.

Comment: You are not using it as per the manual. Look under **Example #5** and you'll see that you didn't `implode()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you wanna pass the headers as array, then you need to specify the header names as array keys! (PHP documentation: "If an array is passed, its keys are the header names and its values are the respective header values.").

There are now 2 solutions.

Solution 1 (Header as string):

```php
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
```

Solution 2 (Headers as array):

```php
$headers   = [
    'MIME-Version' => 'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    'Content-type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
    'From' => "{$name} <{$from}>",
    'Reply-To' => $from,
    'Subject' => $subject,
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion(),
];
```

To check if `mail()` works you can check for the last error.

Example:

```php
$success = mail('example@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
if (!$success) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
}
```

And btw. to avoid any problems with the receiving email servers because of non conform RFC, you should use a mailer class like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer.

Comment: I have tried your solution and error is disappeared. However, still I did not recieve any email.

Comment: You can check for error like in the example I've added to my post. However I really recommend to use a mailer class as mentioned in my answer!